# Could not locate call adapter for class java.lang.Object

Tags: retrofit2, illegalargumentexception

I'm getting this exception in my project with kotlin & suspend & coroutine
#19089618 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Could not locate call adapter for class java.lang.Object. Tried: * retrofit2.e * retrofit2.g

com.hpbr.directhires.service.http.config.AppHttpExtKt$proxyRetrofit$1.java.lang.Object invoke(java.lang.Object,java.lang.reflect.Method,java.lang.Object[])(App...

however I did not call .addCallAdapterFactory(xxx) to add a adapterFactory myself.
the exception only happens sometimes
using retrofit = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"

[retrofit declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNCqX.png)